# Kotlinx Serialization MissingFieldException

Tags: ktor, kotlinx.serialization

I am in the process of converting from Moshi to kotlinx serialization with Ktor and when I try to make a request to get data I am getting this error

> kotlinx.serialization.MissingFieldException: Field 'attachments' is
> required, but it was missing

which makes sense since this specific response does not contain this field

Response Json

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1299418846990921728",
        "text": "This is a test"
    }
}
```

BUT my Serialized class has the `attachments` field as nullable (it is in the response only when it needs to be) so it should just ignore it I thought like it did with Moshi

```
@Serializable
data class ResponseData(
    val id: Long
    val attachments: Attachments?,
    val author_id: String?,
    val text: String
}
```

In my Ktor client setup I have it set to ignore unknown keys

```
private val _client: HttpClient = HttpClient(engine) {
    install(JsonFeature) {
        val json = Json {
            this.isLenient = true
            this.ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        }
        serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json)
    }
}
```

Why is it still saying that the field is required even though its nullable?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I figured it out, apparently even though you mark something as nullable its still considered required.

For it to truly be optional you need to give it a default value so for example the data class would look like this with the nullables

```
@Serializable
data class ResponseData(
    val id: Long
    val attachments: Attachments? = null,
    val author_id: String? = null,
    val text: String
}
```

once you set the value the fields becomes optional and wont throw that exception

Comment: I'm still receiving this error and I've tried every suggestion...

Comment: @Sakiboy check that your explicitNulls variable is set to *false* and not true.
This should resolve the issue of nullable properties not being present in the json, while decoding.

Comment: @oblakr24 that’s what I ended up needing to do in the set up - initialization.

Comment:  it just worked as explained. No need for further changes. My case was exactly the one explained in the question. Thanks!

Comment: For kTor 1.6 this solution is working for 2.0 this solution not woking

Answer (score 43):

As of v1.3.0, you can configure the Json feature to treat absent fields as null, with `explicitNulls = false`

```
install(JsonFeature) {
    serializer = KotlinxSerializer(
        json = kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
            explicitNulls = false
        }
    )
}
```

The documentation for `explicitNulls`:

> Specifies whether null values should be encoded for nullable properties and must be present in JSON object during decoding.
> When this flag is disabled properties with null values without default are not encoded; during decoding, the absence of a field value is treated as null for nullable properties without a default value.
> true by default.

Comment: Oh nice thanks for the heads up!

Comment: More explanation and example at https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/v1.3.0-RC/docs/json.md#explicit-nulls.

Comment: When using koltin multiplatform with `expected` and `actual` classes this seems to be neccessary, even if you provide a default value in the `expected` class for the missing fields.